# Soundcloud Dowloader widget messes with window.data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, widget, soundcloud

Anyone responsible for the Soundcloud Downloader widget found here: http://www.pc-gizmos.com/gizmos/soundcloud-downloader/ ?(It's not official, right?)

Anyway, it's messing with window.data, initializing it to an empty object. This, in turn messes with our site.

I guess we should have known better than using windows.data as is. But we didn't. I think it's more of an issue when a plugin messes with it though.

Any thoughts on this? Is there someone responsible for the widget around? Do you know for a fact about other plugins messing with windows.data in a similar way?

Comment: You need to either namespace your code or modularize your application's javascript and a use an AMD loader like Require.js or CJS with something like Browserify. The reason you're running into this issue is because you're polluting the global namespace (e.g. `window`) by adding properties directly to it (e.g. `window.data`). Admittedly, so is the SoundCloud widget you're using, but is not their responsibility to fix it.

Comment: As I said: "I guess we should have known better than using windows.data as is. But we didn't." It's past tense. I totally agree with you. But to fix this mess we might need 6 months or something. Our code base is old, and huge :P That's why I reached out here. If you (soundcloud downloader) fix yours, we'll fix ours :)

Comment: This, of course, has nothing to do with SoundCloud and goes against our terms of use. The SoundCloud widget namespaces all of its data in `SC` object, as well as JS SDK that lets you control the widget. 

Just like that plugin doesn't respect our terms of use, the same way that plugin doesn't respect the global namespace.